# send POST data from calendar to json_events.php

Tags: fullcalendar

I imagine this is simple but I can't quite get the concept clear.  
Basically I am working on loading events on prev/next click

```
viewDisplay: function(view) { var next = view.title;  }, //alert(next);
```

gives me "November 2012"  
split this 
then

```
events:  { 
url: 'json-events.php',  
type: 'POST',  <br/>
data: { month: month,  
year: year } },
```

So, how to read the POST val in json-events.php
Assuming I am on the right track here. [super newbie]

Answer (score 0):

use as object reference http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

```
<?php
//obtain params
$month = $_POST["month"];
$year = $_POST["year"];

//... get the list of events due to month and year

//create an events array due to docs
$events = array(array('id' => 1, 'title' => 'Event', 'allDay' => true)); 

//return json feed
echo json_encode($events);
?>
```